# GTK+ Custom Accelarator Groups

Tags: application-development, gtk, c, keyboard-accelerators

I have successfully manage to add an accelerator to a menu item with the gtk_widget_add_accelerator() function.

What bothers me is how i can add a custom accelerator that widget.With the first command i can add a shortcut like "Ctrl + A"; but what happens if i want to use the "Up" arrow key or F1 as an accelerator?

Comment: You will probably need to implement this using your own handler. However, I recommend you to ask on stackoverflow.com, as this programming question is barely related to Ubuntu itself.

Comment: I agree that stackoverflow is a better place to ask,on the other hand i am aware that questions regarding application development on ubuntu are valid,so i guess it's not offtopic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to replace <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>something</kbd> with <kbd>something</kbd> itself.

That can be done simply by setting the value of `GdkModifierType`, which is the second from last parameter,to zero.

For instance:

```
gtk_widget_add_accelerator(menu_item.fullscreen, "activate", accel_group, 
GDK_F11, 0, GTK_ACCEL_VISIBLE);
```

This will display <kbd>F11</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>.